# How do I replace from one table in access with the UID from another

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I am trying wash and create a relational database with all of the citizen scientist data collected by my company. I am very new to databases but I'm trying so be kind. Basically, I have a training type table with UID for each training type and a Citizen Scientist table with UID for each citizen scientist. I have a semi-clean table with all of the scientists data with a UID for each row. I want to replace all of the first name and last name columns with the UID from the Citizen Scientist table. I also want to replace all of the training type values with the UID from the training type Table. I really don't even know where to start. I have attached a screen shot of my tables and any help as to where to go next in my little project would be appreciated.

***Enter image description here:***

[image]

Comment: You want to populate the ScientistData table and eliminate CitizenScientists? Add a long integer number field yo ScientistData. Build a query that joins ScientistData and TrainingTypes on the Type fields. Change it to an UPDATE query and use TrainingTypes field to update ScientistData field. Then can delete the CertificationType field from ScientistData. Use Access query builder. Common topic and basic functionality. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment by June7.  First add One foreign key to ScientistData for each table you want to link.  Then run an update query for each linked table to transfer the appropriate foreign key value to ScientistData.

[image]

```
'in the SQL pane you can examine the update query
UPDATE CitizenScientists, ScientistData SET ScientistData.CSID = [CitizenScientists].[CSID]
WHERE (((ScientistData.FirstName)=[CitizenScientists].[FirstName]) AND ((ScientistData.LastName)=[CitizenScientists].[LastName]))
```

To transfer the appropriate trainingtypeid:

[image]

```
UPDATE TrainingTypes, ScientistData SET ScientistData.TrainingTypeID = [TrainingTypes].[TrainingID]
WHERE (((ScientistData.CertificationType)=[TrainingTypes].[CertificationType]))
```

close the update queries and double click each one.  Access will give a warning you are about to update table rows.  Afterward check the ScientistData table and if everything looks ok delete the now unnecessary columns in the ScientistData table.
Finally update the database relationships.

[image]